# Combine two Django queries in a certain order

Tags: python, django, append

I have two django queries in my view. They are as follows:

```
news = News.objects.all()[:8]
posts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
```

I need to combine these two queries together in the following order:

```
[news, post, news, news, news, post, news, post, news, news, news]
```

I am pretty sure that I would have to use `lambda` or do some sort of `count`, but I am a little lost at this point. Should I just be using `count` and `append`?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `[news, post, news news news]` - and post your models. If your news and posts are related; you can do `n.posts_set.all()` or similar.

Comment: Hi Burhan, these two models are not related. Both types get laid out in a for loop in a django template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

```
def selector(seqs, picks):
  iters = [iter(x) for x in seqs]
  for choice in picks:
    yield next(iters[choice])

print list(selector((news, post), (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)))
```